# C++ Accessing Eigen::Tensor Class function from Tensorflow::Tensor object

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

This is probably a stupid question but I'm having difficulty accessing a Eigen::Tensor class function from within a custom op function (void Compute) in tensorflow.

Eigen::Tensor has a member function called "extract_patches" that i'd like to access from inside the op. When I "typeid()" the tensor object, it returns tensorflow::Tensor. How do access the underlying Eigen::Tensor?

Note the code for "extract_patches" is directly from the Eigen documentation.

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/padding.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h"
#include <vector>
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

using namespace tensorflow;

class SauronOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit SauronOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {// Some checks}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {

    //declare temporary storage 
    TensorShape a_shape_temp({act_in_batch, act_in_rows, act_in_cols });
    Tensor a_temp;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_temp( DataTypeToEnum<float>::value,
                                        a_shape_temp,  &a_temp));
    //auto a_matrix = a_temp.shaped<float,3>({{act_in_batch, act_in_rows, act_in_cols });
    auto a_tensor = a_temp.tensor<float,3>();

    //unrelated stuff

    Eigen::Tensor<float, 4> patch;
    Eigen::array<ptrdiff_t, 3> patch_dims;
    patch_dims[0] = filter_height;
    patch_dims[1] = filter_width;
    patch_dims[2] = act_in_cols;

// THIS LINE GENERATES THIS PROBLEM (sorry for yelling)
    patch = a_tensor.extract_patches(patch_dims);

// output for debug
    std::cout<<"type "<< typeid(a_tensor).name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"type "<< typeid(a_temp).name()<<std::endl;
  }
```

Output

```
type N5Eigen9TensorMapINS_6TensorIfLi3ELi1ElEELi16EEE
type N10tensorflow6TensorE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `extract_patches()` returns an `Eigen::TensorPatchOp<...>` (representing the unevaluated expression) and not an `Eigen::Tensor<...>` (representing the evaluated value). To make this work you need to (i) call `.eval()` on the result of `.extract_patches()`, and (ii) declare `patch` as being row-major to obtain an object of the desired type.

The following code compiles for me in a `Compute()` method:

```
Tensor a_temp;
// Initialize `a_temp`...

const auto& a_tensor = a_temp.shaped<float, 3>(
    {act_in_batch, act_in_rows, act_in_cols});

Eigen::array<ptrdiff_t, 3> patch_dims;
patch_dims[0] = filter_height;
patch_dims[1] = filter_width;
patch_dims[2] = act_in_cols;

const auto& patch_expr = a_tensor.extract_patches(patch_dims);

Eigen::Tensor<float, 4, Eigen::RowMajor> patch = patch_expr.eval();
```

Comment: The code compiles, but it segfaults when I try to access the patch. 

patch(0,0,0,0);

Comment: Can you try attaching `gdb` to find out where it segfaults? Note that Eigen doesn't validate any of the arguments, so it's possible to generate an out-of-bounds access when invoking this op.

Comment: I added a single line to the code that accesses the patch. 

"std::cout<<"patch(0,0,0,0) " <<float(patch(0,0,0,0))<<std::endl;"

gdb reports this as the offending line. 

I've tried with and without the float cast to no avail.

Comment: Nevermind. I was being an idiot. The a_tensor data dimensions were too small and it was accessing out of bounds. Thanks.

Comment: @RaviPatel If this answered your question, please accept it (press the grey checkmark next to the answer). This rewards the answerer (+15 points), the asker (+2), and helps guide future visitors who are looking for a solution to your question.